Method to calculate required gear size and teeth size for a rack system for a certain amount of travel?
high school amateur engineer- and first-time poster- here. I'm making a Nerf automatic springer system, and I want to model it. However, I don't know what size rack and gear system I need. I need 60 cubic centimeters of total draw from an air-tight plunger system illustrated, (albeit badly) below. I need to calculate the size of the gear, along with the number of teeth, needed to draw my plunger tube far enough to facilitate it. Finally, I also need to figure out how much space I need to reset the assembly using a cut-out from the gear. (Note- system is on simple rail system not pictured below) 

No information of the diameter of your tank. So no way to calculate how much plunger would need to move. No information on draw length so no way to do meaningful inference on what the mechanical advantage should be.

diameter is 36mm
